# Use Middleware to inject data into ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a `BaseViewModel` that has application-wide data inside of it. Pretend:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
   public string SiteWideNotification {get;set;}
}
```

In reality, this is a complex class, so more than just a string.

I would like to write a piece of middleware that could add to this data for every request if the `ViewModel` extends `BaseViewModel`. Is this possible?

If this is not possible, how do I share a complex class across all my pages?

Comment: I am personally not a fan of that design. I would suggest you create a service that provides the desired data or if it must be a POCO, register it as its own object using the built-in Options pattern (ie `IOptions<MySiteWideOptions>`) and have it injected where needed.

Comment: I was thinking that my Middleware would have a service injected that would actually get the data, and it would be cached. I'll look into the Options pattern.